# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function have_posts() on array

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create drop down for the different products in woocommerce. I am trying to create drop down for bundled product but I am getting this error when I am trying to get posts using WP_query. The code is below:

```
    <?php if($product_coin_carrier_countries-> have_posts()  ) : ?>
        <label for="initial-country-select" style="width:auto;">Select the default country to use for coin mechs to continue:</label>
        <select name="initial-country-select" id="initial-country-select">
            <option value="">Please Select a Country</option>
            <!--?php foreach( $product_coin_carrier_countries as $i => $coin_carrier_country ) { ?-->
            <?php while ( $product_coin_carrier_countries->have_posts() ) : $product_coin_carrier_countries->the_post(); ?>
                <option
                    value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></option>
            <!--?php endforeach; ?-->
                <?php endwhile; ?>
        </select>
        <?php endif;
```

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function have_posts() on array

Comment: What is `$product_coin_carrier_countries`? My guess would be, *not* an instance of `WP_Query`..

Comment: $product_coin_carrier_countries is the variable for all the countries that my company deliver products.

Comment: can you post the code that assigns a value to $product_coin_carrier_countries? Your error lies there.